# Unable to install packages/update in elementary-os

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, elementary-os

I have a problem where I am not able to install anything or update my system from both terminal and the AppCenter. When I install updates it says:

```
Error while installing package: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml', which is also in package libgranite-common 6.1.1+r2107+pkg120~ubuntu6.1.
```

In terminal I get an error of:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
[package name] : Depends: libgranite5 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried removing libgranite5.deb  but it's being created again.
I also did `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and I got the same error
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And did you try the command `apt --fix-broken install`? Please don't answer in a comment, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/672129/edit) your question instead to add new info.

Comment: @Peregrino69 yes, and I also edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

The `granite` package is buggy:

[Bug #1939741](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/granite/+bug/1939741)

> package libgranite5 (not installed) failed to install/upgrade: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml', which is also in package libgranite-common 6.1.0+r2071+pkg119~ubuntu6.1

Comment: But how do I fix it? I couldn't remove the file or uninstall it. (Also I was trying to install elementary tweaks too)